# UITableView cell textlabel not showing text

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have created a label in table view cell but the text i want to display in label is not displaying the below is my code. the label is creating correctly but the text is not showing which i want to display from array.

```
 UILabel *mylabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35,13, 230, 30)];

[cell.contentView addSubview:mylabel];
mylabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: What is the cell's height? Are you sure that the label is "inside" the cell's boundary?

Comment: yes it is displaying properly

Comment: Shouldn't you use mylabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ? Instead of just a row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a new project with Xcode 5 DP4 (iOS 7 project). I put a table view controller in the story board with one prototype cell. Then in the table delegate, I added your code. Looks like this

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UILabel *mylabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35,13, 230, 30)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mylabel];
        mylabel.text = @"Hello";
        return cell;
    }
```

This is working as expected. Have you tried to isolate your code in a new project like I just did? Maybe the problem is unrelated to the actual code you pasted.

Answer (score 1):

Take out all that code and put:

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
```

**EDIT** Try:

```
cell.accessoryView = mylabel;
```

Comment: i need to a custom uilabel

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:row]; it working fine but i nee custom uilabel because that are bit resizing according to my requirment

Comment: becuse the defualt label is not resizing not repositioning

Comment: @Nasir Try [cell addSubview:mylabel];

Comment: @Nasir Try cell.accessoryView = mylabel; instead

Comment: @Nasir Remember check and +1

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [UILabel in UITable do not get display but get display on click in IOS 7 (due to issue with background colour)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186689/uilabel-in-uitable-do-not-get-display-but-get-display-on-click-in-ios-7-due-to/20189385#20189385).

The issue is just because of cell background colour and text colour is same.
Hopes it help you.

Comment: This fixed my issue but i'm a little bit confused why changing the text colour didn't fix it, had specifically set the background colour