# UILabel in UITable do not get display but get display on click in IOS 7 (due to issue with background colour)

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7

1. Referring Image number 1: In ios 6 and 5, the label get display properly in UItable.
   [image: Image_1]
2. Referring Image number 2: In IOS 7, the label do not get display in UItable.
   [image: Image_2]
3. Referring Image number 3: In iOS 7, the label get display on click of cell in UItable.
   [image: Image_3]
4. Below is the code used to write cell in UItable.

   ```
   -(UILabel *)createLabel:(UILabel *)sender1 :(int)x :(int)y :(NSString *)title :(int)size :(int)swidth :(int)ht
      {
        sender1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, swidth, ht)];
        sender1.text = title;
        [sender1 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [sender1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [sender1 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:size]];
        sender1.numberOfLines = 2;  //7

        sender1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        sender1.contentMode = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

       return sender1;
     }
   ```

   I am sure it is not simulator issue.

Comment: Is not the text color white?

Comment: Oh thanks Daniel,now i got actually issue is with background colour. But can you help me knowing why this happening?

Comment: Oh thanks Daniel,now i got actually issue is with background colour. Default it was taking white background.
Thanks now issue got resolved.

Comment: in iOS 7 there is: cell.backgroundColor. to see how iOS 6 you need to do: cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The issue was with the default background colour of the cell.
2. In Ios 6 and 5 it use to set black but in Ios 7 it is set to White.

   [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; is the solution.